# Chain guide/tensioner for 2011 Giant Reign 2 (Press Fit)

Tags: mountain-bike, chain, tension

Can someone recommend a chain guide/guard/tensioner that will be mountable to a 2011 Giant Reign 2 which has Shimano Press Fit and 3-ring crankset? The best I could find is:

- Kore Chain Reactor - available at ebay.co.uk
- [Brand-X Chain Tensioner](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/cz/en/brand-x-chain-tensioner/rp-prod10137)
- Bionicon c.guide 2 - reported as not very durable (breaks)
- [Bionicon c.guide eco](http://www.c-guide.org) - hopefully more durable

I need something that ships to European Union (Czech Rep.). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One possible and modern solution is: none. Go 1x10 or 1x11 with a narrow wide chain ring and a RD with a clutch.